# Mongoose findOne in subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

[image]

This is the structure of my data. I would like to find documents by the object job._id

```
function getQuotesForJob(jobID){ 
    Quotes.findOne({'job.id': jobID}, function (err, quotes) {
        console.log(quotes);
    });
}
```

I have tried this code but it is returning null.

Comment: `Quotes.findOne({'job._id': jobID}` See the difference.

Comment: Tried it and it is still returning null @NeilLunn

Comment: Then you have an incorrect value. Show us the values that you are passing in rather than picture. Text only please.

Comment: At a glance I'm guessing `job` is defined as `Mixed` in your schema. Mongoose cannot "autocast" an `ObjectId` if the type is `Mixed`. You would need to cast manually in such a case. i.e `Quotes.findOne({'job._id': ObjectId(jobID) }`. So you likely need to import `ObjectId` from `Schema.Types` as well.

Comment: @NeilLunn That solved it. Thanks for the help